# Android: Goto HTTP Url on Button Click

Tags: android, http, url, android-activity, android-button

I want to go to a web page on the click of a button in my Android app. So say, I have a button called "Google", when the user clicks on that button I want google.com to open up on the screen. How is this achieved?

Also, is there a way I can gain control back to my app once the user is finished with Google?

Comment: That worked! Quitting the browser comes back to my app, but does not resume my activity?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In your activity do something like this.

```
public void openWebURL( String inURL ) {
    Intent browse = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse( inURL ) );

    startActivity( browse );
}
```

By default, quitting the browser should return to your activity.  However, there may be situations where it will not.

Comment: That worked! Quitting the browser comes back to my app, but does not resume my activity?

Answer (score -1):

This code will take you to the web page

```
public void goToWebPage(String yourUrl) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(yourUrl));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Any reason why your answer is unique from the accepted?