# android activitythread settext error

Tags: android, settext

```
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.itcuties.android.reader/com.itcuties.android.reader.ItemDescriptionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at com.itcuties.android.reader.ItemDescriptionActivity.onCreate(ItemDescriptionActivity.java:18)
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-27 22:53:13.047: E/AndroidRuntime(11744):    ... 11 more
```

And **ItemDescriptionActivity.java**

```
package com.itcuties.android.reader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.itcuties.android.reader.R;

public class ItemDescriptionActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.item);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String item_description = bundle.getString("description");

        TextView desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.item);
        desc.setText(item_description);
    }
}
```

App is getting rss data, showing titles in list view. I am trying to add show description on click but app crashing on click. What can cause these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an `id` to `findViewById()`, perhaps you meant to use `findViewById(R.id.item);`.  If you *still* get the same LogCat errors make sure the layout `item.xml` actually has a TextView with the id: `@+id/item`.

Also not every Activity is started with an Intent and not every Intent has extras, you should make sure that neither of these values are `null` before using them.

---

**Adding another RSS value**

Let's pass the link along with the description:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {   
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ItemDescriptionActivity.class);

    RSSItem item = listItems.get(pos);
    intent.putExtra("description", item.getDescription());
    intent.putExtra("link", item.getLink());
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Next we'll create a new class variable inside `ItemDescriptionActivity`:

```
String item_link;
```

Finally set up the Button to open the link in a web page:

```
item_link = bundle.getString("link");
Button link = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
link.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent browse = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(item_link));
        startActivity(browse);
    }
}
```

Comment: fixed with `findViewById(R.id.Description);`

Comment: I'm pretty sure an activity is always started with an intent. I've never had this happen and I rely on it existing in my apps. If there's a case where the intent would be null I'd love to know to avoid breaking stuff :)

Comment: Here is full code;

https://github.com/m1lesh/ITCutiesReaderApp2/tree/ITCutiesReaderApp

Comment: @Sam Thanks. Now i need to add item link to button on item.xml.

Comment: @dymmeh It's rare when an Activity doesn't have an Intent. I know I have managed to do it in the past, but I may have shot _myself_ in the foot by deleting Intent manually...

Comment: @milesh What type of link? Perhaps web address like this: http://www.www.google.com. You can make those clickable automatically by adding [`android:autoLink="web"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:autoLink) to your TextView's XML.

Comment: @Sam The link of item that parsed from rss.

Comment: @milesh I'm sorry you want a Button to be a link, not a TextView. Please read: [Android: Goto HTTP Url on Button Click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2762861/1267661)

Comment: @Sam Maybe TextView, doesn't matter. Which one is easier? Did you check the [code](http://github.com/m1lesh/ITCutiesReaderApp2/tree/ITCutiesReaderApp) ?

Comment: Ok, I looked through your code and let's use the Button you already set up.  In `onItemClick()` pass the link value as well as the description: `intent.putExtra("link", listItems.get(pos).getLink());`, next in `ItemDescriptionActivity` read the link into a new variable, then find the Button, and set up an OnClickListener, finally use the in an Intent like: [Android: Goto HTTP Url on Button Click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2762861/1267661)

Comment: @Sam Ok, got first step. How will i set up an OnClickListener with link on button?

Comment: @Sam Can you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124924/android-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class) ?