# android ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class

Tags: android

```
    02-28 01:49:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(23024): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-28 01:49:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(23024): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.appname.android/com.appname.android.ITCutiesReaderAppActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.appname.android.ITCutiesReaderAppActivity" on path: /data/app/com.appname.android-2.apk
    02-28 01:49:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(23024):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
    02-28 01:49:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(23024):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
...
    02-28 01:49:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(23024):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    02-28 01:49:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(23024):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    02-28 01:49:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(23024):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-28 01:49:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(23024): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.appname.android.ITCutiesReaderAppActivity" on path: /data/app/com.appname.android-2.apk
    02-28 01:49:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(23024):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    02-28 01:49:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(23024):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    02-28 01:49:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(23024):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    02-28 01:49:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(23024):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
    02-28 01:49:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(23024):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
    02-28 01:49:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(23024):    ... 11 more
```

I started to get this error after i delete the extra folder in app folder with same app files (and change app name, fixed names in all files). How can i fix this?

Here is manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.appname.android"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".ITCutiesReaderAppActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ItemDescriptionActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Post your manifest so we can double check, but you might just need to clean your project and run it again.

Comment: @milesh Seems you have a package name mismatch, is `com.appname.android` the package of your app?

Comment: @A--C Yes it is. Not appname in real, i just didn t use real name. But changed all realname with appname in error and manifest.

Comment: It has been solved earlier through a nice post.
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866431/android-activity-classnotfoundexception-tried-everything>

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You *do* have a package mismatch error, it needs to be:

```
package="com.haber29.android.reader"
```

Since `reader` is the next subpackage and *this* is the subpackage that contains the Activities.

And don't forget, you can specify the fully qualified name for each Activity, to prevent confusion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.haber29.android"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name="com.haber29.android.reader.ITCutiesReaderAppActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.haber29.android.reader.ItemDescriptionActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem today，because my library include the `android-support-v4.jar` not matching with my demo. I deleted the library's `android-support-v4.jar` and copied my demo's jar putting it in my library and it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my antivirus software (Avira for Mac) grabs dex files after every build I make and puts them into quarantine. After I stopped Avira, my project builds and runs.